# Pascal's triangle and Fibonacci sequence explanation

Tags: fibonacci, discrete-mathematics, factorial, pascals-triangle

Okay I need to redraw the pascal's triangle and explain the Fibonacci sequence embedded in it.. And i need to observe over 12 rows of the triangle (which ends on the number 144 in the fibonacci sequence)  -- I understand this part as i am just explaining how each row diagonally forms the sum of the Fibonacci numbers.

But I need to use the fact that the rth number in the nth row of the triangle is 
C(n, r) = n!/r! n-r!

This last part is whats confusing me.. How can i use C(n,r) to explain the Fibonacci sequence in the triangle??

Please Help. Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a discrete math question, which is more appropriate at math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following problem :

In how many ways can you go up a ladder of n steps if you can take either a single step at a time or 2 steps at a time?

Solution 1 : Let's construct a recurrence relation for this problem. It's pretty clear that the recurrence would be something like this : `a(n) = a(n-1) + a(n-2);` where `a(1)=1` and `a(2)=2`
Thus, the answer for `n` would be the `(n+1)th` fibonacci term.

Solution 2 : Each unique way of climbing up the ladder corresponds to a unique sequence of 1's and 2's which adds up to n. The number of such sequences thus would be our answer. Let's start counting such sequences :

Number of sequences without a 2 = `$ {n \choose 0 } $`.
Number of sequences with one 2 = `$ {n-1 \choose 1 } $`.

.
.
.
and so on.
In case of even n, the last term would be `$ {n/2 \choose n/2 }  $`.
And for odd n, it would be `$ {(n+1)/2 \choose (n-1)/2 } $`.
As you can see, These are the diagonal terms in a pascal's triangle.

As these two solutions compute the same result, hence they must be equal. Thus we get the relation between Fibonacci numbers and the diagonals of a pascals triangle.

Refer the link 
http://ms.appliedprobability.org/data/files/Articles%2033/33-1-5.pdf
for anymore doubts.